# qPython qpython.qtype.QException: b'length'

Tags: python, kdb, qpython

So I'm trying to fire the following query (synced) to kdb+:

`q.sync('{select from trade where date>x,date<y, sym=z}', 'instr81', '2014.04.14', '2017.04.14')`

When executed it gives me `raise QException(self._read_symbol())
qpython.qtype.QException: b'length'` and I do not get where it is coming from. I've tried other types such as numpy.string_ or and regular bytes (b'instr81') but no luck there.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of arguments looks off: from your q.sync call, it looks like `x` is `'instr81'`, `y` is `'2017.04.14'`, and `z` is `'2017.04.14'`.

Your length error is because you're comparing a list of n dates with a string of length m.

I'm *pretty* sure your query will also fail because of your date types - you need to send actual dates (as `numpy.datetime64   D` per [the documentation](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type-conversion.html)) instead of strings.

You are also correct in needing to convert your string - as it is, q will be receiving the "symbol" as a string type because it has not been sent as a `numpy.string_` type.

Better syntax might look like the below - also observe the more-performant q code using `within` rather than `date>x,date<y` - this will save you reading in *all* partitions after x and then subsetting for `date<y`. This is if you wish to make your select *inclusive* - I noticed that your query is exclusive, so in the query in your example, you should never get any data back (your start == your end so 0 results).

```
> import numpy as np
> q.sync(
    '{[x;y;z]select from trade where date within(x;y),sym=z}', 
    np.datetime64('2014-04-14','D'), #start date
    np.datetime64('2014-04-14','D'), #end date
    np.string_('instr81')
 )
```

Comment: Hi there! Yes I noticed just now that the order was incorrect. I'll give  the date thing a try!

Comment: @HighSociety cool - see sample code added in edits (I'm sneaky like that)

Comment: Love your sneakyness, love the within function (had never heared of it). The `b'lenght` exception is gone now, but it swapped places with a `b'rank` exception.. My understanding is that if 'rank' is raised by kdb, there are to many parameters for the query. This isn't the case here right?

Comment: PS: as you might have noticed, I'm not experienced with kdb at all :-)

Comment: Ha - it's not an easy one to get to grips with! Yeah, my test just threw the same 'rank exception. Amend the function to 
`{[x;y;z]`[...] and it works - wonder if this isn't just a quirk of qPython

Comment: Ah no - just did some digging, and it's to do with how q parses `select` statements in lambdas - because [x;y;z] wasn't specified, the select statement's `y` and `z`are parsed to refer to other columns in `t` - the function essentially becomes unary in x rather than trinary in x,y,z. Quirk of `select` parsing rather than qPython!

Comment: Yesss! You saved the day! Thank you a lot!! One more thing: I'm somewhat confused by how qPython determines what variables (in this case x,y,z) to replace by the parameters that are passed. Is this just anything that's not recognized as a keyword?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I guess I'll have to do some reading on kdb myself!

Comment: From reading the qPython code at https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython/blob/master/qpython/qconnection.py I can see that it defines

    `def query(self, msg_type, query, *parameters, **options):`

And sends all non-named arguments (*parameters) as the parameters to the function (as long as there are 8 or fewer). All named arguments are assumed to be arguments (**options) to the actual `sync` call rather than to the query it sends to the q process.

Comment: Ahh right, and x, y and z can be anything thats not in kdb's namespace? say: foo, bar and something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150204/discussion-between-simon-major-and-high-society).